# Redirect loop issue in PHP website

Tags: php, redirect-loop

I have been working on CS50's problem set 7, in which we have to make a financial website using MVC. I completed the website and it is working absolutely fine on my local machine.

But when I upload the files to hosting (free) service's server and try to access it I get a Redirect Loop error. Here is the link to it: http://ghazilajpal.byethost6.com/finance/public/

Here is code of `login.php`:

```
<?php

    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 

    // if user reached page via GET (as by clicking a link or via redirect)
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET")
    {
        // render form
        render("login_form.php", ["title" => "Log In"]);
    }

    // else if user reached page via POST (as by submitting a form via POST)
    else if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // validate submission
        if (empty($_POST["username"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide your username.");
        }
        else if (empty($_POST["password"]))
        {
            apologize("You must provide your password.");
        }

        // query database for user
        $rows = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", $_POST["username"]);

        // if we found user, check password
        if (count($rows) == 1)
        {
            // first (and only) row
            $row = $rows[0];

            // compare hash of user's input against hash that's in database
            if (crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])
            {
                // remember that user's now logged in by storing user's ID in session
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["cash"] = $row["cash"];
                // redirect to index.php (portfolio)
                redirect("/");
            }
        }

        // else apologize
        apologize("Invalid username and/or password.");
    }

?>
```

**Update**

Here is login_form.php:

```
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autofocus class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
<div>
    or <a href="register.php">register</a> for an account
</div>
```

And this is config.php. This also has a redirect:

```
<?php

    /**
     * config.php
     *
     * Computer Science 50
     * Problem Set 7
     *
     * Configures pages.
     */

    // display errors, warnings, and notices
    ini_set("display_errors", true);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // requirements
    require("constants.php");
    require("functions.php");

    // enable sessions
    session_start();

    // require authentication for all pages except /login.php, /logout.php, and /register.php
    if (!in_array($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], ["/login.php", "/logout.php", "/register.php"]))
    {
        if (empty($_SESSION["id"]))
        {
            redirect("login.php");
        }
    }

?>
```

I hope its easy to understand. I don't know where the problem lies and how to fix it.

I could have asked it on cs50.stackexchange.com but a similar question is already there with no answer.

Comment: This is not enough to help you. Your redirection loop is in login.php, with GET method, and that's all I can tell from your code. Maybe, try posting what is in include/config.php (stripping any private data from there) and also login_form.php

Comment: @Palantir I edited the question as you asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some debugging using bhushanRJ's advice of using `die ()`. And found out that the issue is with URLs. So using `/finance/public/login.php` instead of just login.php (same for other array items) solved the issue.

However CSS and JS files weren't loading. Similarly, fixing their URLs in templates fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Is it coming in this code block always?

```
if (crypt($_POST["password"], $row["hash"]) == $row["hash"])
            {
                // remember that user's now logged in by storing user's ID in session
                $_SESSION["id"] = $row["id"];
                $_SESSION["cash"] = $row["cash"];
                // redirect to index.php (portfolio)
                redirect("/");
            }
```

if yes then here have a probelm.
change redirect with die(); to verify.

And Please provide some more inputs from you to clarify more.

Comment: I have added more code. And tried your solution but still redirect loop

Comment: Thanks your advice helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

When I got a loop it was because I hadn't started the session by putting "session_start()"